# Is it possible to generate hidden-definitions for a single file?

Tags: sorbet

When running `srb init` on a large Rails application, the process uses a lot of memory (10GB+) and takes a long time (upwards of 10 or 15 minutes) to complete. Is is possible to update hidden definitions for a single file or sub-directory in order to speed-up this process?

I am especially thinking of the case where a new gem or file-change requires an update to the hidden definitions but I don't want to re-initialize the entire project.

Answer (score 1):

Computing hidden-definitions.rbi is necessarily whole-program wide. The algorithm is:

- load all code in your project, including gems
- run sorbet over all code in your project, including RBIs that were already created for gems
- output an RBI containing the diff of the previous two steps.

So fundamentally, hidden-definitions.rbi must be computed for an entire project.

Comment: The hidden definitions file has a section for each class/module. During that final step you describe, is it not possible to compute a diff for a subset of classes/modules? Can you also clarify why (in step 2) it is not possible to run sorbet over only a subset of the code?